# PercentRelativeLayout Layout_Width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following xml file, the problem is that my `ImageView` is not being displayed as I would expect it to.

I end up with 1 row that is 20%/80% where the left part contains an 0*0 Imageview. [ScreenDump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilk2y.jpg)

What i would expect it to look like, would be an ImageView scaled to 50% the height of the row.

I tried removing the `layout_width`/`layout_height` in the ImageView but if I do so i end up with `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_width attribute` that states I have to add a `layout_width`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Collapser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LowerFirstContainer"
            app:layout_widthPercent="20%"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#00ff00">
          <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:src="@drawable/Icon"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="100%">
          </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>       
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't `ImageView` child of `LinearLayout` not `android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout` !!! So width and height 0 means Should it be visible?

Comment: You can use `LinearLayout` with weights here. And setting `width` and `height` to 0 will make the view invisible

Comment: Well since this LinearLayout is a child of PercentRelativeLayout i would have expected that you can use percentWidth/Height within its Child.